# How can I split text in parts in javascript

Tags: javascript, split

How can I split text in parts in javascript: I have

> Ingrédients Purée de fruits (mangue 25%, banane*), purs jus de fruits (pomme*, fruits de la passion* 18%, orange), 100% des ingrédients agricoles issus de l'agriculture biologique.

I want ths split in : 
`text[0]= Ingrédients Purée de fruits (mangue 25%, banane*)
text[1]= purs jus de fruits (pomme*, fruits de la passion* 18%, orange) 
text[2]= 100% des ingrédients agricoles issus de l'agriculture biologique`

So it is split with "," but"," is also used somewhere else!, and you have to skip that!!

Comment: Can you articulate what the logic is for when a split should happen?

Comment: I want to split the ingredients list from food products in parts of single ingredient, so I can say This ingredient has this characteristics, But some times ingredients are build with one word and sometimes a whole sentence is used for only one single inredient with percentages included where i'm not interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `),` with some special character preserving `)` at the end and then `split()` it:

```js
var str = "Ingrédients Purée de fruits (mangue 25%, banane*), purs jus de fruits (pomme*, fruits de la passion* 18%, orange), 100% des ingrédients agricoles issus de l'agriculture biologique.";
var text = str.replace(/\),/g, ')&').split('&').map(x=>x.trim());
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `.match` instead, and alternate between (non-comma, non-parentheses characters) and (parentheses `\(` followed by non-`)` characters, followed by a `)`). This way, commas will only result in a new item in the array result if the comma is *outside* of parentheses:

```js
const str = `Ingrédients Purée de fruits (mangue 25%, banane*), purs jus de fruits (pomme*, fruits de la passion* 18%, orange), 100% des ingrédients agricoles issus de l'agriculture biologique.`;

console.log(
  str.match(/(?:[^,(]+|\([^)]+\))+/g)
);
```

To additionally trim out the leading spaces:

```js
const str = `Ingrédients Purée de fruits (mangue 25%, banane*), purs jus de fruits (pomme*, fruits de la passion* 18%, orange), 100% des ingrédients agricoles issus de l'agriculture biologique.`;

console.log(
  str.match(/(?:[^ ,(][^,(]+|\([^)]+\))+/g)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless you have something specific to split the array in. it can't be done

For now i see that string can be split on "," if it does not occur inside the "()"

So here is the code for that

```
var str = "Ingrédients Purée de fruits (mangue 25%, banane*), purs jus de fruits (pomme*, fruits de la passion* 18%, orange), 100% des ingrédients agricoles issus de l'agriculture biologique.";
var regex = /,(?![^(]*\)) /;
var splitString = str.split(regex);
console.log(splitString);
```